# Sorting array by alphabet will not function correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, alphabetical

Code I am talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/sbe8yzv0/8/

I want to sort my array by the name with two buttons: First button sorts it by length and second buttons sorts it by alphabet.

When I sort by alphabet it doesn't want to function. It randomly puts the data in different positions. I have tried multiple ways of sorting it and they all act funky and doesn't sort it completely alphabetically. What can I do to make it actually sort the name in array by alphabet?

```
    function sortNameAlphabetically(a, b) {
        return a.name > b.name;
    }
```

The sort by length is working as intended except when it sorts alpabeticly after length it does it bakwards. How do I make sure it sorts the right way?

```
    function sortNameByLength(a, b) {
        return b.name.length - a.name.length;
        a.localeCompare(b);
```

Comment: [Your first comparison function is invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785/1048572).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the `sortNameAlphabetically` method to

```
  function sortNameAlphabetically(a, b) {
        return a.name.localeCompare( b.name );
    }
```

updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbe8yzv0/9/)

Also, statement after return statement in `sortNameByLength` method is not reachable and not required anyways.

```
    function sortNameByLength(a, b) {
        return b.name.length - a.name.length;
    }
```

Comment: Awesome. Do you know how I can fix the second problem?

Comment: @Thomasdc simply `return a.name.length - b.name.length;`

Comment: But how do I make it sort it alphabetically after being sorted by length then? So if I have ABA, BBBB, AAAA, AAA. It should be AAAA, BBBB, AAA, ABA

Answer (score 1):

Part two of the question, to maintain the alphabetical sorting after length sorting, you can use a logical OR with the localeCompare method.

```
function sortNameByLength(a, b) {
    return b.name.length - a.name.length || a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this and it doesn't work. Nothing happens. https://jsfiddle.net/sbe8yzv0/10/

Comment: please try edit. you need to address the name property.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks a lot! :)